# libpd with Android - Patch doesn't play sound when using expr in patch

Tags: java, android, puredata, libpd

I am using a patch to implement a peaking filter (using biquad~) given freq/q/gain.

The patch works fine in Pd, however when using it with Android Studio, I don't get sound. No errors are shown in Android Studio, the patch loads fine, just no sound.

If I take away the section of the patch converting the f/q/g parameters into filter coefficients, and just give in 5 random coefficients, the patch works fine.

Thus, I presume the issue is with the expr object as besides that, there isn't much else extra.
Is there anything specific which I would have to add to my Android Studio project due to using expr?

[image: Biquad Patch with Expr]

This patch doesn't work.

[image: Biquad Patch without Expr]

This patch does work.

My java file looks like this:

```
package com.example.mark.pdaudioio;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.puredata.android.io.AudioParameters;
import org.puredata.android.io.PdAudio;
import org.puredata.android.utils.PdUiDispatcher;
import org.puredata.core.PdBase;
import org.puredata.core.utils.IoUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView volumeTextViewJava;
    SeekBar volumeSeekBarJava;
    int volume = 0;

    private PdUiDispatcher dispatcher;

    private void initPD() throws IOException{
        int sampleRate = AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate();
        int inpch = AudioParameters.suggestInputChannels();
        PdAudio.initAudio(sampleRate, inpch, 2, 8, true);
        dispatcher = new PdUiDispatcher();
        PdBase.setReceiver(dispatcher);
    }

    private void initGUI(){
        Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.onOffSwitch);
        onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                float val = (isChecked) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
                PdBase.sendFloat("onOffPD",val);

            }
        });

        volumeTextViewJava = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volumeTextView);

        volumeSeekBarJava = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);
        volumeSeekBarJava.setMax(100);
        volumeSeekBarJava.incrementProgressBy(1);
        volumeSeekBarJava.setProgress(0);
        volumeSeekBarJava.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int volProgress, boolean fromUser) {
                volume = volProgress;
                float volumeFloat = (float) volume;
                PdBase.sendFloat("volumePD", volumeFloat);
                volumeTextViewJava.setText("vol: " + volProgress);

            }
            public  void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
            public  void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadPDPatch() throws IOException{
        File dir = getFilesDir();
        IoUtils.extractZipResource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.simplepatch),dir,true);
        File pdPatch = new File(dir, "Biquad_WithExpr.pd");
        PdBase.openPatch(pdPatch.getAbsolutePath());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            initPD();
            loadPDPatch();

        }catch (IOException e){
            finish();
        }

        initGUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        PdAudio.startAudio(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        PdAudio.stopAudio();
    }
}
```

Here is a link to my full Android Studio project.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aorji4heum8jvbc/PDAudioIO.zip?dl=0

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues when using libPD within both Android and iOS. It looks like most of your expressions could be handled using native pd-vanilla objects (but it will be a bit more verbose), so recoding the expressions would likely fix the issue.  If you're not already doing so, it's good practice to test your libPD patches via PD-Vanilla rather than the PD-extended or PD-L2Ork.